# Querying in DynamoDB (with hash-and-range primary key) without providing hash key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

When querying in DynamoDB (with a hash-and-range primary key), is it essential to provide the hash key or can you simply search by providing the range key? This is my use case: I have a table which has the following "schema": Category#Domain (String) - Hash key GroupType#GroupName (String) - Range key Some other string fields like UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy etc.

I have to frequently do there two things: 1. Given a Category#Domain, get all the matching items. 2. Given a GroupType#GroupName, get all the matching items.

Both the operations are fairly frequent so I do not want to use scan. Is there an effective way to do this in DynamoDB? Is there a better way to design the schema (more tables, secondary indexes etc.)? Any suggestion would be helpful.
Someone suggested using Global Secondary Index but with that my question is will I be able to make the range key of my main table as the hash key of my gsi? I know all the "keys" are copied over automatically but this would help me only if I can make GroupType#GroupName as the hash key in the gsi so as to be able to query on it. Also, is there any special way to handle gsi from DynamoDBMapper? Will I need to create a new POJO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an effective way to do this in DynamoDB?

It sounds like you are looking for [Global Secondary Indexes (GSI)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html). You have your table which has:

- Hash key: Category#Domain
- Range key: GroupType#GroupName
- Other attributes

And based off this table it sounds like you want to have a GSI:

- Hash key: GroupType#GroupName
- Range key: depends on design (not necessary in GSI)
- Other attributes that are wanted

> will I be able to make the range key of my main table as the hash key
>   of my gsi?

Yes, the example on the [developer guide does just this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html).

Since the table's primary key attributes are always projected into an index, the Category#Domain attribute is also present. You can also select which attributes you want to project onto this index. GSIs also [do not need to have a range key](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/):

> Also, is there any special way to handle gsi from DynamoDBMapper? Will
>   I need to create a new POJO?

DynamoDBMapper provides the ability to do this. I'm not sure which AWS SDK version it was released with (maybe 1.7?). You should not need to create a new POJO, but if you are trying to deal with existing tables you will not be able to add GSIs to them right now (support for [online indexing](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-json-and-more/) was announced last month). You can use the annotation [`DynamoDBIndexHashKey`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBIndexHashKey.html) and [`DynamoDBIndexRangeKey`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBIndexRangeKey.html) annotations in your POJO in the same way you use them currently.

**Update 2015/1/27**: [Online Indexing is now available](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-dynamodb-update-online-indexing-reserved-capacity-improvements)